# Using borders on column divs in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a row with a few columns. I want each div to have a 1px border around it, but wherever two divs touch, there shouldn't be overlapping borders (2px). I want it like a grid, but without using tables as this has to be responsive. In the picture below, I want the first effect, not the second. I've tried borders with border-collapse but it did nothing, even when adding "display:table-cell".

[image]

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-lg-2"></div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-lg-2"></div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-lg-2"></div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-lg-2"></div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-lg-2"></div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-lg-2"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it's probably not the best solution (may be the easiest) but you could just add

```
div {
    margin-top:-1px;
    margin-left: -1px;
}
```

so then the borders overlap and it looks like a 1px border all around

Comment: This is definitely the easiest solution, kind of hacky, but it works: http://www.bootply.com/I1IrivYxMv you could also use `nth-child` selectors to do this as Adam mentions above, however, that would require you to set up different CSS rules at each breakpoint and is also not as cross-browser friendly as this solution.